# Write a method that get's 2 numbers as Input and return third different number

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

I'm struggling a bit with this question.
You should return a different number without using ANY conditions / loop's in your code.

My way of thinking is that maybe the direction for the solution is using bit manipulation?

Comment: Where do you get those 3 numbers from? Are they hard-coded, passed as additional parameters or some other alternative?

Comment: @Paul, I suppose the question is about `int notEqualToAorB(int a, int b)` function

Comment: take the second to last digit of a and change it, concatenate the last digit of b that has been changed.

Comment: @Paul yep, you got a,b as input and your output should be c - different number

Comment: @Henry can you explain with more details pls? thanks:)

Comment: @miss_M I wrote an answer.

Comment: @miss_M, this question needs more specifics, are we talking about two's complement signed integers?

Comment: And another question. `abs` is a condition or not?

Comment: Sounds a bit like homework.

Comment: @DAle good question. I think that not.

Comment: @MrSmith42 well nop..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`((a&1)|(b&2))^3` is a number between 0 and 3 that differs from `a` in the first bit, and differs from `b` in the second bit. (This uses C notation: `&` is bitwise and, `|` is bitwise or, and `^` is bitwise xor).

Comment: okay, but if both a,b are equal to 0 ? so only the ^ will change them ?

Comment: @miss_M, c will be equal to 3

Answer (score 1):

To make sure the third number is different compose it by taking parts of the original numbers that have been changed. For example if the numbers are 123 and 789 you can take the "2" of the first number and make it a "3" and the "9" of the second number and make it a "0". Concatenate these two to get "30". This cannot be the first number because the second to last digit is different and it cannot be the second number because the last digit is different.

This can be formulated without loops and ifs (assuming integer arithmetic):

```
(a+10)/10%10*10 + (b+1)%10
```

Comment: Great! 
but, if both a,b are equal, lets say they are equal to 0. -->
a=b=0
So this formula isn't work though for this case :/

Comment: No problem, the result would be 11.

Comment: That's right! 
what is the logic that made you take the "second" number from "123" and no lets say the first?

Comment: What about `a = 9, b = -2`?

Comment: @DAle As written, it only works for positive numbers. To extend it for negatives you can for example take their absolute value before doing the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

If the two given numbers are:

- input1
- input2

You could simply return:

```
abs(intput1) +abs(input2) +1
```

You need to call `abs()` to avoid things like `1 + (-1) +1 = 1`